# TooManyRequests: 429 Too Many Requests while running tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

Through the basic Academic Research Developer Account, I'm using the Tweepy API to collect tweets containing specified keywords or hashtags. This enables me to collect 10,000,000 tweets per month. Using the entire archive search, I'm trying to collect tweets from one whole calendar date at a time. I've gotten a rate limit error (despite the wait_on_rate_limit flag being set to true) Now there's an error with the request limit.

here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import tweepy


# function to display data of each tweet
def printtweetdata(n, ith_tweet):
        print()
        print(f"Tweet {n}:")
        print(f"Username:{ith_tweet[0]}")
        print(f"tweet_ID:{ith_tweet[1]}")
        print(f"userID:{ith_tweet[2]}")
        print(f"creation:{ith_tweet[3]}")
        print(f"location:{ith_tweet[4]}")
        print(f"Total Tweets:{ith_tweet[5]}")
        print(f"likes:{ith_tweet[6]}")
        print(f"retweets:{ith_tweet[7]}")
        print(f"hashtag:{ith_tweet[8]}")


# function to perform data extraction
def scrape(words, numtweet, since_date, until_date):
    
    # Creating DataFrame using pandas
    db = pd.DataFrame(columns=['username', 'tweet_ID', 'userID',
                            'creation', 'location', 'text','likes','retweets', 'hashtags'])
    
    # We are using .Cursor() to search through twitter for the required tweets.
    # The number of tweets can be restricted using .items(number of tweets)
    tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_full_archive,'research',query=words,
                        fromDate=since_date, toDate=until_date).items(numtweet)
    
    # .Cursor() returns an iterable object. Each item in
    # the iterator has various attributes that you can access to
    # get information about each tweet
    list_tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets]
    
    # Counter to maintain Tweet Count
    i = 1
    
    # we will iterate over each tweet in the list for extracting information about each tweet
    for tweet in list_tweets:
            username = tweet.user.screen_name
            tweet_ID = tweet.id
            userID= tweet.author.id
            creation = tweet.created_at
            location = tweet.user.location
            likes = tweet.favorite_count
            retweets = tweet.retweet_count
            hashtags = tweet.entities['hashtags']
        
        # Retweets can be distinguished by a retweeted_status attribute,
        # in case it is an invalid reference, except block will be executed
            try:
                text = tweet.retweeted_status.full_text
            except AttributeError:
                text = tweet.text
            hashtext = list()
            for j in range(0, len(hashtags)):
                hashtext.append(hashtags[j]['text'])
        
        # Here we are appending all the extracted information in the DataFrame
            ith_tweet = [username, tweet_ID, userID,
                    creation, location, text, likes,retweets,hashtext]
            db.loc[len(db)] = ith_tweet
        
        # Function call to print tweet data on screen
            printtweetdata(i, ith_tweet)
            i = i+1
    filename = 'C:/Users/USER/Desktop/الجامعة الالمانية/output/twitter.csv'
    
    # we will save our database as a CSV file.
    db.to_csv(filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    consumer_key = "####"
    consumer_secret = "###"
    access_token = "###"
    access_token_secret = "###"
    
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)
    
    since_date = '200701010000'
    until_date = '202101012359'
    
    words = "#USA"
    
    
    # number of tweets you want to extract in one run
    numtweet = 1000
    scrape(words, numtweet, since_date, until_date)
    print('Scraping has completed!')
```

I got this error:

```
TooManyRequests: 429 Too Many Requests
Request exceeds account’s current package request limits. Please upgrade your package and retry or contact Twitter about enterprise access.
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I believe this is due to the Sandbox quota. For a premium account it would be more.
[Tweepy API Documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html)

You may check out this answer here - [Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61278571/understanding-twitter-api-rate-limits-using-sandbox-environment-and-searchtweets)

Comment: thank you for answering me. Does this means that I only have 50 requests for the month, with up to 100 Tweets per request even when I have an academic research application? it was working perfectly yesterday but now it is occurring this error?

Comment: This looks like the case here. If you check the error message, it says "Please upgrade your package and retry or contact **Twitter** about enterprise access." So Tweepy being a wrapper is still using Twitter API behind the scenes.