# Tweepy TooManyRequests: 429 workaround

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm doing academic research and I'd need to retrieve all Elon Musks' tweets. I started with Tweepy, but now I can't get past the TooManyRequests: 429 Too Many Requests error.

I found an old question about the same issue, but it wasn't solved [Understanding Twitter API rate limits using sandbox environment and searchtweets API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61278571/understanding-twitter-api-rate-limits-using-sandbox-environment-and-searchtweets)

Could someone help me to work around this? In case it matters, I'm planning to perform a sentiment analysis on the tweets, and I'll filter in Pandas tweets referring to Tesla and compare them to the stock performance in an event study setup. I need all the tweets in order to control the "marketing effect" of Elon Musk tweeting in general.

Here is my current code:

```
import tweepy
import config_academic

tweepy.client
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=config_academic.ACADEMIC_BEARER_TOKEN)
query = 'from: elonmusk'

start_time = "2010-06-29T00:00:00Z"
end_time = "2022-06-29T00:00:00Z"


for tweet in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_all_tweets, query=query, max_results=100, start_time=start_time, end_time=end_time).flatten():
    print(tweet)
```

Comment: What happens if you try the [client’s `wait_on_rate_limit`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html?highlight=Client#tweepy.Client)? Otherwise, have you inspected the response coming back that tells you what your limit is and when it refreshes?

Comment: This was a great point! I wasn't aware of that parameter. Now it's running and saying "Rate limit exceeded. Sleeping for 900 seconds." Let's see what happens.